# Serverless Deploy fails: At least one of ProvisionedThroughput, ... is required

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I am trying to deploy new Lambda Functions and API Gateways to AWS using the npm serverless package. The new functions are being deployed on top of previously existing functions, and new DynamoDB tables are being created along with the new lambda functions.

The deploy is failing with the following error:

```
An error occurred: authDB - At least one of ProvisionedThroughput, BillingMode, UpdateStreamEnabled, GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdates or SSESpecification or ReplicaUpdates is required (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;
```

The 'authDB' is a table that already exists in DynamoDB. The serverless.yml file for this database table is as follows:

```
authDB:
  Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
  DeletionPolicy: Retain
  Properties:
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: key
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: key
        KeyType: HASH
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 5
      WriteCapacityUnits: 5
    TableName: "auth-db"
```

I'm not sure as to why I am receiving this error, since the 'ProvisionedThroughput' is defined.

[UPDATE] This authDB config is the same has not been changed since it was originally deployed... the only changes to the serverless.yml aside from the new functions/database resources is the addition of the serverless-plugin-split-stacks to bypass the CloudFormation 200 resource limit. This is the configuration of the serverless-plugin-split-stacks:

```
custom:
  splitStacks:
    perFunction: true
    perType: false
    perGroupFunction: false
```

Comment: You said authDB already exists in a previous template, correct? If so can include what the old `.yml`.

Comment: @thenerdassassin the authDB config is the same in the previous .yml as well.

Comment: Richard, were you able to try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-plugin-split-stacks#advanced-usage) for **serverless-plugin-split-stacks** it states:

"Many kind of resources (as e.g. DynamoDB tables) cannot be freely moved between CloudFormation stacks (that can only be achieved via full removal and recreation of the stage)"

I am not 100% sure this is the error being thrown, with a bad message, but to test it out. I would try applying your CloudFormation templates to an empty, new AWS account and see if the succeed.